# foundation tooltip is not working

Tags: jquery, tooltip, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use Foundation tooltip for a project. The project is under Yii framework.

At the end of the body, I added the jQuery, Foundation JS, and initialize Foundation.

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $(document).foundation();    
  })
</script>
```

Then I added the generic HTML class

```
<span data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="Tooltips are awesome, you should totally use them!">extended information</span>
```

The result is just a simple generic browser tooltip.

All other Foundation javascript features doesn't work either, reveal, dropdown, etc... The only thing that works is orbit.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you see if you're getting any js errors on your page?

Comment: Nope, the console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Seems like a sass problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link foundation.css to your page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by including custom.modernizr.js (before foundation scripts)

Answer (score 0):

move all scripts to the end of the HTML file just before body end